# Watch a directory in python and parse latest generated text file

Tags: python, parsing, directory

I'd like to ask if there's any way we could watch a directory in python and parse the latest text file being generated on the directory.

Tho i have this start up code which parse a certain text file.

```
import time

def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = open(r'\\some directory\files.txt',"r")
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
        print line,
```

See the bold **files.txt** i need that to be dynamic by watching the directory for newly generated text files and switch to the latest text file and parse it.

It will run on Windows XP service Pack 3

I'm using Python 2.7

Directory i'm watching is also using windows XP

Thank you.

Comment: What OS will it run on?

Comment: Windows XP Service pack 3 @MartinKonecny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for new files, repeatedly get a list of files currently in the directory with `os.listdir('directory')`. Save the entries in a set and calculate the difference of the set with the previous set.

```
# Initialize before an event loop:
old_entries = set()

# You need a loop that calls two handlers, each handler returning soon.
# Inside your loop, check for a "new file" event this way:
now_entries = os.listdir(r'\\some directory')
now_entries.symmetric_difference_update(old_entries)
for new_entry in now_entries:
    handle_new_file(new_entry)
```

Your program needs to listen for two events:

- New file in the directory.
- New line in the old file.

You call `follow()`, which is like an event handler that never returns. I think you want that handler to return to one main event loop that checks for each kind of event. Your `follow()` function never returns because it `continue`s within the `while True` infinite loop unless a new line is added to the file for it to `yield`. It will never yield if no more lines are getting added to that file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the `FindFirstChangeNotification` API

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

> The approach here is to use the MS FindFirstChangeNotification API, exposed via the pywin32 win32file module. It needs a little explanation: you get a change handle for a directory (optionally with its subdirectories) for certain kinds of change. You then use the ubiquitous WaitForSingleObject call from win32event, which fires when something's changed in one of your directories.

Essentially because the Windows OS is responsible for managing creation/modification of files, you can ask it to let you know immediately when a file is changed/created.